# SQLite, ASCII Characters 0x20 to 0x7E Check Constraint

Tags: sqlite, check-constraints

I have the following table where I'm trying to limit the column "name" to ASCII characters ranging from 0x20 to 0x7E (all printable ASCII characters). Why is my check constraint not working?

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
( 
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(name NOT GLOB '*[^\x20-\x7E]*'),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

For instance:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES("Tom");
```

Expected: Should add a touple with name: "Tom" to the table (as the inserted name only consists of printable ASCII characters). Result: CHECK constaint failed: test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes are not special in SQL strings. '\x20' is 4 individual characters, not an escaped single character, for example. So your `GLOB` pattern always matches (Because T is not a character in the set), and the `NOT` makes it, and thus the constraint, fail.

Comment: Even without a solution: Cheers! Just for the extended explanation.

Answer (score 0):

###### Solution

```
name NOT GLOB cast(x'2a5b5e202d7f5d2a' as TEXT)
```

###### Explanation

To assure all characters in a string are printable ASCII, we try to look for characters that aren't. If no such character is found, the string is printable ASCII. Conceptually the query could look like this:

```
name NOT GLOB '*[^\x20-\x7E]*'   -- (doesn't work in SQLite)
```

Here the `GLOB` operator matches any character not in `0x20-0x7E` and since we negate the expression with `NOT`, the query resolves to logical `true` if no characters outside the range are found. However, SQLite does not let you escape hex characters in string literal, e.g., `'\x20'` is not a hex-encoded space character. As a work-around, we provide the same `GLOB` pattern as a byte sequence `x'2a5b5e202d7f5d2a'` and cast it to `TEXT`, leaving us with:

```
name NOT GLOB cast(x'2a5b5e202d7f5d2a' as TEXT)
```

Now this may be too ugly for legit developers, but for us naughty rascals messing with SQL Injection this is just perfect.

---

<sup>PS: I implemented a similar logic in my Blind SQL Injection framework. Interested readers can find it [here](https://github.com/pruzko/hakuin/blob/30c08a8a4459fa8461ec5aa96828c1e5aae1c133/hakuin/dbms/SQLite.py#L47).</sup>